# MySql PATH doesn't work

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to create a PATH for mysql, I create the file :

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

And add this to the file :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

But when I do "mysql -v", it doesn't work..

when I do echo $PATH :

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

My etc/path :

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I did not found any answer...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is not a configuration file. It's a shell script. You have to execute it to make it have any effect.

Either logout and login again, or issue:

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

Comment: thanks ! Yes I did not knew that, I simply execute it with :         '. ~/.bash_profile'